# does ANTLR4 build automata at some point?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

as I understand the latest ANTLR4 went away from building static DFA tables for the lexer and for parser and now they do it at runtime. Is this correct? Could someone please explain in general how ANTLR4 works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our recent paper describes the mechanism in [excruciating, academic detail](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273188534_Adaptive_LL%28%2A%29_Parsing_The_Power_of_Dynamic_Analysis). Section 3 provides a high level overview:

> Instead of relying on static grammar analysis, an ALL(*) parser adapts to the input sentences presented to it at parse- time. The parser analyzes the current decision point (nonterminal with multiple productions) using a GLR-like mechanism to explore all possible decision paths with respect to the current “call” stack of in-process nonterminals and the remaining input on-demand. The parser incrementally and dynamically builds a lookahead DFA per decision that records a mapping from lookahead sequence to predicted production number. If the DFA constructed to date matches the current lookahead, the parser can skip analysis and immediately expand the predicted alternative.

We use an augmented transition network (ATN) to represent the grammar but build DFA using an algorithm very similar to the subset-construction algorithm of NFA-to-DFA conversion fame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. I need to parse in "real time" as the user types the code. This is for syntax highlighting etc. Do you think that your approach will be performant enough to handle this?

Comment: @akonsu -- easily, subject to many caveats. Primary is to be able to initiate a new full parse after each keystroke on a background/non-display thread, discarding the thread if it does not complete before the next keystroke.  'Typically' each parse will complete with plenty of time for a screen update.

Comment: definitely fast enough. See the shootout with other tools in the paper. Also many tools use antlr for IDEs, including NetBeans and my plugin for Intellij.

Comment: If I want to do only lexical analysis, only regular grammar, no context free grammar, then should I use ANTLR4 over others like Flex from a performance perspective.

Comment: Well, if you literally only want regex, maybe just use a regex lib or flex?